# work with IBM MQ from Java

Tags: java, kotlin, websphere, ibm-mq

I have a problem with connection in IBM MQ from java
this code

```
 val cf: MQQueueConnectionFactory?
    var mqConnection: QueueConnection? = null
    var session: QueueSession? = null
    var sender: QueueSender? = null
    var value = ""
    try {
        cf = MQQueueConnectionFactory()
        cf.hostName = host
        cf.port = port
        cf.queueManager = queueManager
        cf.transportType = transport
        cf.channel = channelName
        cf.clientReconnectOptions = WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_Q_MGR
        cf.clientReconnectTimeout = 3600

        mqConnection = cf.createQueueConnection()
```

> drops exception "JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode
>   '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED')"

when I try create connection  `cf.createQueueConnection()`

I don't understand what is a problem.
I use   ibmmq lib **9.0.2.0** version, but this code doesn't work with   7.5.0.1 version too

Comment: You should have the MQ admin review the queue manager's `AMQERR01.LOG` to determine why you are receiving the `2035` error.  There are be a few different causes and the resolution depends on what the causes is.  Both answers provide possible solutions for two common causes.  If you can update your question with what is found in the queue manager's log then it will be helpful for someone to provide you a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MQRC 2035 means the user doesn't have the appropriate authorities to connect to the queue manager. The reason can be found in the `AMQERR*.log` in the queue manager `errors` directory. `CHLAUTH` is enabled by default. You need to add `CHLAUTH`  rules. Following link provides details on create/modify `CHLAUTH`

[IBM MQ 7.5.0 > WebSphere MQ > Reference > Administration reference > MQSC reference > The MQSC commands > `SET CHLAUTH`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q086630_.htm)

If you want more details on CHLAUTH then go through the following link:

[CHLAUTH Made Simple: Common Scenarios and Examples and How to Verify them with RUNCHECK](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27041997&aid=1)

Comment: Do you mean that these actions need to be done on the server side?
If this should be done by me in Java code or IBM MQ client side, then I don't know    how do it

Comment: These have to be done on the queue manager side and not on the client side

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll try to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

> mqConnection = cf.createQueueConnection()

You should/need to pass the UserId and Password for the connection.

i.e.

```
mqConnection = cf.createQueueConnection("myUserId", "mypwd");
```

Comment: it's ok, but еhe owner of the service(IBM MQ) says that access to the queue is done without a password and login