# MQ Connection fail (2035) in java maven project but work well with MQ7.5 Jar

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I have a working source to connect MQ 7 by using com.ibm.mq JAR lib version 7.5.0.8.

```
private Hashtable<String, Object> mqProperties = new Hashtable<String, Object>();

mqProperties.put(MQConstants.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, ip);
mqProperties.put(MQConstants.PORT_PROPERTY, port);
mqProperties.put(MQConstants.USER_ID_PROPERTY, username);
mqProperties.put(MQConstants.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password);
mqProperties.put(MQConstants.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channelName);
mqProperties.put(MQConstants.CCSID_PROPERTY, "1098");

queueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName, mqProperties);
```

and no problem. I port my connect source to maven app and use latest version of MQ access lib

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.mq/com.ibm.mq.allclient -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
    <version>9.3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Same source cannot connect and get 2035 error (user)?

```
ReaderQueueThread.openQueue(), Queue_UserName <suny> is not Valid!MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2035'.
```

What should I do more to connect? My env is windows 10 and MQ 7.5 on win 2008.

Comment: Did you mean MQRC 2058 - MQRC_Q_MGR_NAME_ERROR? I am not aware of any MQRC 2508. Does a queue manager with the name you provided via queueManagerName variable exist?

Comment: sorry, I had mistaken and corrected my question. Correct error no is 2035. Both env  (jar or maven method) are same

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51062840/work-with-ibm-mq-from-java/51064023#51064023

Comment: You should really check what showed up on the queue manager's AMQERR01.LOG. This will provide the true reason for the 2035.

Comment: My guess is it's how the user is being presented, 7.5 would send it in MQMD. 9.3 would send it in MQCSP.

Comment: I disable password parameter setting and connected well. It seems that MQ75 do not need password, then when using maven V9 lib by not sending password it switch to anonymous authentication. Thanks for all friends advise.